# Is there any way to display CPU, memory information in vim's status bar?

Tags: neovim

Is there any way to display CPU, memory information in vim's status bar?

I use vim mostly on my own computer, so I don't want to use tmux.

My vim is neovim and the version is v0.6.1.

My OS is Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Seems like `statusline` might be what you want. Explained and discussed in a [similar Reddit thread here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/nffnoh/is_there_any_plugin_available_for_displaying_ram/).

Comment: It should be possible, but be careful not to let it update too often because Vim's status bar updates...a lot. You could easily bog Vim down trying to keep that information current.

Comment: Your Vim is not Vim.